# React router - redirect all routes except one

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to implement protected routes in React. 
Following is my implementation

```
if (isAuth()) {
      routesToRender = (
        <React.Fragment>
          {/* <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" /> */}
          <Route path="/" exact component={props => <Dashboard {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={props => <Dashboard {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/settings/" exact component={props => <Settings {...props} />} />
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    } else {
      routesToRender = (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Route path="/signup/" exact component={props => <Signup {...props} />} />
          <Route path="/" exact component={props => <Login {...props} />} />
          <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    }
```

If not authenticated I want to redirect all the routes to root URL which is `*` and I use `<Redirect from="*" to="/" />` for that. But I also want to be able to access `/signup`.

How do I redirect from all routes except one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing hardcoded routes for authentication, you should instead write an AuthRoute HOC,

```
const AuthRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    if(isAuth) {
        return <Route {...rest} component={Component} />
    }
    return <Redirect to="/" />
}
```

and use it like

```
<React.Fragment>
      {/* <Redirect exact from="/" to="/dashboard" /> */}
      <AuthRoute path="/" exact component={props => <Dashboard {...props} />} />
      <AuthRoute path="/dashboard" exact component={props => <Dashboard {...props} />} />
      <AuthRoute path="/settings/" exact component={props => <Settings {...props} />} />
 </React.Fragment>
```

Any Route that you do not want to Authenticate, will be written down as a normal Route

Comment: But how do I redirect all the random routes to root?

Comment: Also in this case, even the normal routes are redirecting me to `/`

Comment: ```
<Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isAuth() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
    }
  />
```
This works for me.

Comment: @SoorajChandran, As I said, any normal Route which has to go through without the auth flow needs to be rendered as a `Route` and not `AuthRoute`. Also the random routes can simply be Redirect to `/` using `<Redirect from="*" to="/" />` But please note that, you should make use of Switch while rendering Routes